# Offseting a Ray from camera before casting

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

Hello dear Unity game developers,

Today i have a question that seemed easy but i had a hard time solving it. In order to explain what i'm trying to achieve i made a simple illustration.

[image: ray offset illust]

I am current developing a simple mobile game which uses drag and drop system; however, as you can guess when people touch the screen the fingers usually block the view of touch position therefore i instantiate the objects with a little offset. Right now i have this simple code which works just fine achieving what i want.

```
 Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition)
 if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, someDistance))
 {
       Instantiate(prefab, hit.point + MyOffsetVector3, Quaternion.identity)
 }
```

However, this system has flaws like the hit location being different than the spawn location which prevents you to do certain things like object avoidance. Therefore before i return a ray from camera's screen point which uses pixel coordinate Input.MousePosition, i want to offset it like in the illustration so i can achieve a offsetted instantiate location that is the actual hit.point from the raycast which i can check for some conditions. In simple terms, i want unity to behave like i touched higher on the screen than i have currently.

If any of you know how to offset a Pixel Coordinate which is equivalent to for example (0, 0 , 2) in world coordinates regardless of the pixel size of the phone, i might use some help.

Thanks for the help, Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could offset screen point by [Screen.height](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-height.html)*0.1f (whatever number works for you).
You would be offsetting by a percentage of the screen height.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
    Vector3 offset = camera.transform.up * 0.1 //offset upwards by some value
    Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition)
    ray.origin += offset //add offset to ray start
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, someDistance))
    {
       Instantiate(prefab, hit.point + MyOffsetVector3, Quaternion.identity)
    }
```

Comment: It works with a little adjustments man thanks, i didn't know i could change the origin of the ray.